# Parse JSON text in a textfield (My result is NULL)

Tags: ios, json, parsing, textview

I am making an iOS application which communicate with an database via an API. The API sends valid JSON to the application but the application gives no error but another result: NULL.

Here is my code for the iOS app:

```
 // Start hud
 MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
 hud.labelText = @"Zoeken...";

 return TRUE;
 }

    - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
   {    
 [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
if (request.responseStatusCode == 400) {
    textView.text = @"Invalid code";        
} else if (request.responseStatusCode == 403) {
    textView.text = @"Code already used";
} else if (request.responseStatusCode == 204) {
    textView.text = @"No content";
} else if (request.responseStatusCode == 412) {
    textView.text = @"Precondition Failed";
} else if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
    // NSString *naam = [responseDict objectForKey:@"DEB_NR"];

    NSString *part0 = [responseDict objectForKey:@"klntnr"];
    NSString *part1 = [responseDict objectForKey:@"klntnm"];
    NSString *part2 = [responseDict objectForKey:@"adrs"];
    NSString *show = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r%@\r%@\r%@" , part0 , part1 , part2 ];

   // if ([unlockCode compare:@"com.razeware.test.unlock.cake"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Resultaten: %@", show];
  //  } else {
       // textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Resultaat: %@", unlockCode];
  //  }

  } else {
      textView.text = @"Unexpected error API ERROR";
  }

}

 - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
 {    
 [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
 NSError *error = [request error];
  textView.text = error.localizedDescription;
  }

 @end
```

Thanks in advance,

Maurice.

Answer (score -1):

It would really help if you just show the JSON string;
But try this

```
else if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {

NSError* error;
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSArray *responseObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
NSString *part0=@"";
NSString *part1=@"";
NSString *part2=@"";

for (int i=0; i<[responseObj count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [responseObj objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *part0 = [dataDict objectForKey:@"klntnr"];
    NSString *part1 = [dataDict objectForKey:@"klntnm"];
    NSString *part2 = [dataDict objectForKey:@"adrs"];
}
NSString *show = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r%@\r%@\r%@" , part0 , part1 , part2 ];
textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Resultaten: %@", show];
}
```

Comment: If you're going to the trouble to switch over to NSJSONSerialization you should take the little extra effort required to check the error code.

Comment: And you're assuming that the result will be an array when the original code assumes a dictionary.  Why is your guess better than the OP's?

Comment: @HotLicks OP is following this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app , and he doesnt even display JSON, so there is no way understand exact problem, speaking from experience of same tutorial, I thought he receives a dictionary of array and he needs to get first elements of it.

Comment: If the problem were due to assuming dictionary when it should be an array, the error would be unrecognized selector.  If there is doubt, the class of the object should be tested.

Comment: @HotLicks So I have to change the dictonary to an array?

Comment: @SpaceDust Yes I used that tutorial and I want to expand that for my own situation.

Comment: @Maurice - You have to dump the JSON source, consult json.org & study the spec to see what the JSON is doing, and then select whether the outermost structure is an "object" (dictionary) or an array.  Anything else is just fumbling in the dark.  Like I said, show us the JSON.

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks for your help!